# How to handle multiple spinners on selected item? I'm not getting what to do

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

```
private void getData(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getStudents(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getStudents(JSONArray j){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            students.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_LOCATION));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students));
}

/*SELECT BRANCH*/

private void getData3(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config_spinner3.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result3 = j.getJSONArray(Config_spinner3.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getStudents3(result3);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getStudents3(JSONArray j){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            students3.add(json.getString(Config_spinner3.TAG_BRANCH));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    spinner3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students3));
}

/*SELECT BRANCH ENDS HERE*/


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    /*
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    */
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code. It may be help you.

Your activity implements with AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

```
Spinner spinnerBloodGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerBloodGroup);
spinnerBloodGroup.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;

    if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinnerGender) {

        genderId = ListData.listGender.get(position).getId();

    } else if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinnerBloodGroup) {

        bloodGroupId = ListData.listBloodGroup.get(position).getId();

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: Still, i didn't get how to do it.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, may be it will help you

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if(parent.getId() == R.id.spinner1)
        {
          String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();               
        }
        else if(parent.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
        {
          String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
        }
    }
```

OR try to another way

```
        ArrayList<LocationObjects> country=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<LocationObjects> country1=new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if(parent.getId() == R.id.spinner1)
            {
              String text1 = country.get(position).getLocationName();              
            }
            else if(parent.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
            {
              String text2 = country1.get(position).getLocationName(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Im fetching the data from the back end. But instead of text1 what i can declare? It is showing error for text1.

Comment: Please declare text1 as String like see my updated code

Comment: Still im not able to fetch the data. Im getting the location but based on location city should come. Im not getting that.

Comment: check updated answer  if still you are getting error please explain problem more clearly

Comment: ive 2 spinners in xml. once the location is selected in the first spinner based on that the second one should show(Like if i selected India all the states names in india should display).. But right now if you see my code above im just displaying the result. it is not up to the mark. and in onselected listner im not getting how to write the code for that.